# How do I install the driver for a DLink DGE-528T?

Tags: server, drivers

```
additionally if i try to install the latest driver from TP-Link i get this error message.
# make clean modules
make -C src/ clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src'
rm -f *.o *.ko *~ core* .dep* .*.d .*.cmd *.mod.c *.a *.s .*.flags
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src'
make -C src/ modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.34.7-0.4-default/build SUBDIRS=/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.34.7-0.4-obj/i386/default'
make -C ../../../linux-2.6.34.7-0.4 O=/usr/src/linux-2.6.34.7-0.4-obj/i386/default/. modules
CC [M] /root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.o
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:378:21: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_phy_timer_t_handler’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:525:60: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_timer_handler’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:561:60: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_init_board’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:615:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘SET_MODULE_OWNER’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:621:12: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_init_one’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:783:12: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:794:5: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘open’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:795:5: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘hard_start_xmit’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:796:5: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘get_stats’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:797:5: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘stop’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:798:5: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘tx_timeout’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:799:5: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘set_multicast_list’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:816:12: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_open’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1052:34: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1064:51: error: ‘SA_SHIRQ’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1064:51: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1064:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘request_irq’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/src/linux-2.6.34.7-0.4/include/linux/interrupt.h:122:1: note: expected ‘irq_handler_t’ but argument is of type ‘enum irqreturn_t (*)(int, void *, struct pt_regs *)’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_hw_PHY_reset’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1140:34: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_hw_PHY_config’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1168:34: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_hw_start’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1244:34: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_init_ring’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1399:34: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_tx_timeout’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1475:34: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_start_xmit’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1508:34: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_interrupt’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1749:34: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_close’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1812:34: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_set_rx_mode’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1914:34: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_get_stats’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:1980:34: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘priv’
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c: In function ‘r1000_init_module’:
/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.c:2009:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_module_init’
make[5]: *** [/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src/r1000_n.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [_module_/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src] Error 2
make[3]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.34.7-0.4-obj/i386/default'
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/TG-3269_100628/r1000/src'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:**

*Prep your system for building packages*

By default, Ubuntu does not come with the tools required. You need to install the package build-essential for making the package and checkinstall for putting it into your package manager. These can be found on the install CD or in the repositories, searching in Synaptic Package Manager or the command-line apt-get:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential
>   checkinstall linux-headers-$(uname -a)

**Step 2 :**

*Download the driver from [here](http://tsd.dlink.com.tw/downloads2008detailgo.asp)* and find the driver description like this :

DGE-528T B1 Driver v5.00 (for WW) -> this is the only driver that support linux 2.4 and 2.6.

**Step 2 :**

extract the zip file and find the linux folder in Driver.

unzip DGE-528T_B1_Driver_v5.00.zip

then :

If you are running the target kernel, then you should be

able to do :

```
make clean modules  (as root or with sudo)

make install

depmod -a
```

The media can be forced to one of the 5 modes as follows.

```
    Cmd: "insmod r1000 media=SET_MEDIA"        



    We need to key in "insmod r1000.ko media=SET_MEDIA" instead of 

    "insmod r1000 media=SET_MEDIA" in FEDORA 3        



    For example:

     "insmod r1000 media=0x04" will force PHY to operate in 100Mpbs Half-duplex.



     SET_MEDIA can be:

            _10_Half        = 0x01

            _10_Full        = 0x02

            _100_Half       = 0x04

            _100_Full       = 0x08

            _1000_Full      = 0x10
```

Force media type for multiple cards could be performed as:

```
     "insmod r1000 media=0x04,0x10"
```

which force PHY to operate at 100Mbps half-duplex and 1000Mbps full-duplex.